# How do I return all of one column in a table using Eloquent and Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Simple question, but the posts I've seen on this site seem to usually ask the question in reference to relationships to other DBs.

I'm sure it's simple, but I am trying to create a dropdown, populated by all of the `tag_name` column, sending the corresponding `ID`, all from my `tags` table.

I've tried `Tag::lists('tag_name','id')`, but is lists deprecated in 4?

What is the typical way? `Tag::all()->tag_name` also seems obvious to me, but that is also not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try:

```
Tag::all()->lists('tag_name', 'id');
```

Comment: It works, however it's overkill: It fetches all the rows AND creates models for them, then it calls `lists` on the collection. Instead you should use `Tag::lists('tag_name', 'id')` - it will run pretty much the same query (with different select clause) and create only the array you need.